# Webpack 2 и watch для partial sass файлов

Tags: sass, webpack2

**Дано:** Есть sass файл который внтри себя делает @import других partial sass файлов.

- main.sass
- _partial1.sass
- _partial2.sass

Webpack настроен на билд только main.sass файла.

**Проблема:** При запуске Webpack в режиме watch он почему-то не смотрит за partial sass файлами, а смотрит только за изменениями main файла. А хочется чтобы при изменении одного из partial sass файлов происходил ребилд.

**P.S.**
На сколько я знаю режим watch в Webpack работает по дереву файлов которые он строит в момент первого билда. Но почему-то брать partial sass файлы он не хочет.